# two struct declaration with ( and ) in one line c programming

Tags: c

hey im reading some code and I see this:

`const struct struct_entry *(*enter)(const struct struct_entry *entry);`

can you explain to me how can I dessect it ?

what I understand is it is creating two struct's one called **enter** and another **entry** am I right ?

Comment: It might be worth spending time at [The Function Pointer Tutorials](http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html) page, which explains all you need to know about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`... (*...)(...)` is a function pointer.

---

There are three types here.

`enter` is a pointer to a function.

Its sole parameter `entry` is a pointer to a `struct struct_entry`, this struct being constant.

Its return value is a pointer to `struct struct_entry`, this struct being constant. (That `const` shouldn't be there.)

---

Some of the above was obtained by applying the [Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Comment: did you mean "is a struct struct_entry" ?

Comment: Why should that `const` not be there?

Comment: @Eric Postpischil Well, I'm making the assumption that it's just the parameter or similar being returned. Consider the situation when the parameter isn't const from the caller's perspective. Now you need a cast in the caller to remove the improperly-added constness on the returned value. From what I've seen, people prefer to have the constness removed by the function instead, allowing assignment to const or not const as appropriate in the parent.